# Encrypt zip folder on download and then decrypt with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography, node-crypto

So I have an application that downloads a zip folder with a bunch of audio files in it. I want to encrypt that zip file on download, and then be able to decrypt the zip file at some other point in the application so that it can be extracted. I have basic logic for encryption and decryption using Node's Crypto package and AES-256 with CTR mode, but I can't seem to get a usable zip file at the end of the process.

Here's my http.get request that I use to download the zip file

```
http.get(fileURI).on('response', function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        let encryptedChunk = encrypt(chunk);
        writeStream.write(encryptedChunk);
    }).on('end', function() {
        writeStream.end();
    })
})
```

So that get request encrypts every chunk of data as its downloaded and sends it to the writeStream which is open to a specific file, and then the writestream is ended when the zip is done downloading. This seems to encrypt correctly, in the sense that I can't open the zip file (a Windows cannot open the folder error pops up).

My encrypt function is very basic that is called in the http request looks like this:

```
function encrypt(data) {
    try {
        let cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', key); // key is a random string
        let encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(new Buffer(data, "utf8")), cipher.final()]);
        return encrypted;
    } catch (exception) {
        console.error(exception);
    }
}
```

I then have a function that creates a readStream that attempts to decrypt this file, it looks like this:

```
function decryptzip() {
    // assume there are a bunch of necessary filepaths up here

    let readStream = fs.createReadStream(downloadedZipFilePath);
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(newDecryptedZipFilePath);
    readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
        let decryptedChunk = decrypt(chunk);
        writeStream.write(decryptedChunk); // the goal of this write stream is to have a usable zip file once it closes
    }).on('finish', () => {
        writeStream.end();
    })
}
```

And then my actual decrypt function looks like this:

```
function decrypt(data) {
    try {
        let decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ctr', key); // same key used in encrypt
        let decrypted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(data), decipher.final()]);
        return decrypted;
    } catch (exception) {
        console.error(exception);
    }
}
```

Both these encrypt and decrypt functions work find with plain text, but the "decrypted" zip file is still unusable and gives me the "Windows cannot open the folder error" when I try to see whats inside. I really have no clue what I'm doing in terms of this stuff so any help would be appreciated, I'm pretty lost lol.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are taking chunks of the file, encrypting them separately and then writing those to disk. What you end up with is a bunch of different encrypted parts of a file rather than one encrypted file. You'll want to utilize Node's stream functionalities here probably:

```js
const http = require('http');
const { createWriteStream, createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { createCipheriv, createDecipheriv, randomBytes } = require('crypto');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const pipelineAsync = promisify(pipeline);

const downloadAndEncryptFile = async (uri, path) => {
  const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(uri).on('response', resolve).on('error', reject);
  });

  const secret = randomBytes(32);
  const iv = randomBytes(16);

  await pipelineAsync(
    response,
    createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', secret, iv),
    createWriteStream(path),
  );

  return { secret: secret.toString('base64'), iv: iv.toString('base64'), path };
};

const decryptFile = async ({ path, secret, iv }) => {
  const secretBuf = Buffer.from(secret, 'base64');
  const ivBuf = Buffer.from(iv, 'base64');

  await pipelineAsync(
    createReadStream(path),
    createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', secretBuf, ivBuf),
    createWriteStream(`${path}-decrypted`),
  );
};

downloadAndEncryptFile('http://www.google.com/', 'encrypted-path')
  .then(decryptFile);
```

In order to encrypt, we:

1. make the request and receive a response object, which is a readable stream,
2. pipe the *entire* response through one cipher,
3. pipe the output of the cipher to a file

By utilizing streams, we keep a lower memory footprint and can pretty efficiently encrypt and decrypt even large files.

The above snippet is ready to run (tested on Node v12.18.3).

Answer (score -2):

The Node crypto API is still sufficiently low-level enough that a lot can go wrong. For example you might want to add an HMAC to the encrypted data to ensure its integrity.

My proposal would be to use a Javascript binding of libsodium or similar so you get an even more high-level API. The native bindings I could find weren't making the most mature impression or using outdated versions of libsodium.

As such, my recommendation would be to go with https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js as it has undergone a professional audit. The API is very straightforward, too.

Comment: I agree with your advice, but this doesn't answer the question at all!